# Remove attribute present in different class names

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I would like to get rid of the "href" attribute only present in certain class elements.

```
String html="<div>This is my example: 
<a class="class1" href="www.example.com">Hello World</a>. More data: 
<a class="class2" href="www.nuisance.com">
      Keep this text but remove its reference
</a></div>"
```

Desired output:

```
String newhtml="<div>This is my example: 
<a class="class1" href="www.example.com">Hello World</a>. More data: 
<a class="class2"> 
     Keep this text but remove its reference
</a></div>
```

I was using JSoup to get rid of attributes using `NewTraversor()` and `trasverse`, however, it removes all the attributes specified, and I would like to remove only the ones associated with certain classes. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Use JSoup to get the class name, check if it's equal to the class you are looking for, and only remove the href attribute for matching elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not familiar with `JSoup`, but based on what I found [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) it can be done as follows:

```
doc.select("a.class2").removeAttr("href");
```

Comment: I got the same hint from R. Oosterholt answer too... I will try it, thanks!

Comment: @Rodo yeah, the point goes to him, I just tried to translate it to `JSoup`

Comment: I included that inside my `NodeTraversor()` method, it works nice.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?
It can be simply done using jQuery like this:

```
jQuery('a.class2').removeAttr('href')
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Actually no, but if I used it, would it cause a conflict with JSoup (which I am already using to parse the html doc)?

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like this -

```
     String html="<div>This is my example: 
         <a class="class1" href="www.example.com">Hello World</a>. More data: 
         <a class="class2" href="www.nuisance.com">
         Keep this text but remove its reference
        </a></div>"

     Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "http://example.com/");
     Elements links = doc.select("a.class2");
     Element link = links.first();
     link.removeAttr("href");
```

It should work.